# upload file in django admin without model and get rid of InMemoryUploadedFile [solved]

Tags: django, django-admin, django-file-upload

I want to upload a CSV file in the admin that adds information to a model. In case you can live with a normal form and not a extension of  `change_form.html` and not overwriting `response_change` (I tried that fist) this is how it can be done:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class StoreAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ## add an extra field:
    upfile = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = "__all__"
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(StoreAdminForm, self).clean()

        if "upfile" in self.changed_data:
            ### file validation on file type etc here ..
            ## file is valid:
            ## next lines deal with the InMemoryUploadedFile Type
            path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT.joinpath("___tmp___")
            tmp = default_storage.save(path, ContentFile(cleaned_data["upfile"].read()))
            
            ## open file
            with open(tmp_file, encoding = "utf8") as f:
                data = f.readlines()
            ## ...
```

I hope this helps everyone, I lost some time with not knowing how to deal with the `InMemoryUploadedFile` types.

Comment: try request.FILES["uploadCSV"]

Comment: this is exactly my problem, `request.FILES` is empty.

Comment: can you move the accept tag to the first input tag

Comment: I tried this, but could not solve my problem. I will post a solution later myself. Thanks for you support. I made a workaround.